# Variable not found in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript, slim-lang

I am new to coffee scripting..This is my first script and is not working..

```
html
 head title='hello world'
  css:
   h1{
    color: blue;
    }
  coffee:
     number   = 42
     opposite = true
     saybye = () ->
      alert 'hello'+number
      ''        
body
  h1 
   |hello world
  input type="button" onclick="saybye()" value="sayhello"

scss:
 $blue: #3bbfce;

 h2{
  color: $blue;
 }
```

It says saybye is not found and should I always end with some expression which will get return. Is there a way to stop the return call?

Comment: Please look at the generated HTML and try to debug from there…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what Slim does but CoffeeScript usually gets wrapped in a function to avoid namespace pollution. So, your CoffeeScript probably ends up being converted to JavaScript something like this:

```
(function() {
  var number, opposite, saybye;

  number = 42;

  opposite = true;

  saybye = function() {
    alert('hello' + number);
    return '';
  };
})();
```

The result is that `saybye` is not visible to your HTML.

You really shouldn't be using `onclick` in 2012, you should be binding to the event through the modern API. If you're using jQuery, you'd do it like this:

```
coffee:
  number   = 42
  opposite = true
  saybye = () ->
    alert 'hello'+number
    ''  
  $ -> $('input[type=button]').click saybye
```

If you're not using jQuery (or similar), then you'd do it the hard way using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) on the raw DOM object. Alternatively, you could put them in `window` yourself and bypass scope protection:

```
coffee:
  window.number   = 42
  window.opposite = true
  window.saybye   = () ->
    alert 'hello' + number
```

As far as returning something goes, don't worry about it, return whatever makes sense. Sometimes returning `undefined` makes sense, sometimes it doesn't. If there is no obvious return value then just let CoffeeScript do what it wants, go with this:

```
saybye = () ->
  alert 'hello' + number
```

and move on to more interesting problems.

Comment: are these variables not part of the window array ..?? so if I have variable defined with coffee: and I have a regular script using  script then it will not have access to that variable...as you see I mentioned that I am learning coffee..and I didn't want to complicate it with jquery...so the onclick.

Comment: @coool: No, they're wrapped in a `(function(){...})()` specifically to avoid polluting the global (AKA `window`) scope. You could put them into `window` yourself though, I've added an update to cover that.

Comment: @coool: Not that I know of and such a default would just make it easier to shoot yourself in the foot; we already have more than enough ways to cause problems for ourselves, we don't need another.

Comment: Here is a short cut rather than saying the entire window. use  @saybye

Comment: You're probably better off using an explicit `window` rather than the context sensitive `@` (AKA `this`).

Comment: do you how we can set -b option in sinatra for coffee-script